# Does the covariant derivative commute with the contraction?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Let $T_{ij}$ be a tensor on a Riemannian manifold. Is it true that
$$
\nabla_l g^{ij}T_{ij} = g^{ij} \nabla_l T_{ij}
$$
?

I guess that this is true if I show that 
$$
\nabla_l g^{ij} = 0. 
$$
I started  computing and I have:
$$
\nabla_l g^{ij} = \partial_l (g^{ij} ) + \Gamma^{i}_{lk} g^{kj} + \Gamma^j_{lk} g^{ki}
$$
but I don't know how to carry on the computation... 
Any hint or suggestion will be very appreciated!

Comment: For me $\nabla g = 0$ is part of the *definition* of $\nabla$. What is your definition? If it's a formula for $\Gamma$ in terms of derivatives of the metric, then substituting this in your last equation and simplifying should yield zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a requirement and is  equivalent to the  analog of the leibniz rule.

For instance, consider
\begin{equation}
d g(v,u) = \nabla g(u, v)+ g(\nabla u, v)+ g(u, \nabla v) \hspace{1cm} 
\end{equation}
$g$  is a $(0,2)$-tensor   and $u,v$ are two vector fields.  In index notation this is gien by

\begin{equation}
{(g_{ij} v^i u^j)}_ {,\   k}= g_{ij, k}
v^i u^j +   g_{ij} v^i_{\   ,k} u^j + 
 g_{ij,k}  v^i u^j_{\   ,k}
\end{equation}

The left hand side here is saying first contract and then differentiate, the right hand side is you first differentiate using the Leibniz rule for the product  and then contract.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I still don't understand how to use the leibniz rule to get $\nabla_l g^{ij} = 0$.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe I got it... 
$$
0 = \nabla_l (g_{ij} g^{ij}) = (\nabla_l g_{ij})g^{ij} + g_{ij} (\nabla_l g^{ij}) = g_{ij} (\nabla_l g^{ij}).
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: @Onil90 Seems correct to me!